# MySQL偏差値を求める方法

Tags: mysql

`subject` と　`point` カラムがあるtestテーブルに対してsubject毎の偏差値（標準偏差ではなく）を取得したいのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？

標準偏差と平均値は下記のような感じで取れました。

```
SELECT subject, STD(point),  AVG(point) from test_table　GROUP BY subject;
```

このsubject毎の標準偏差を使って(point－subject毎の平均point)÷subject毎の標準偏差×10＋50）を計算し、出力もしくはカラムに格納したいです。

Answer (score 1):

携帯で雑に書いていたため解答を修正します。
手元にMySQLの環境がないのでTransact-SQLで回答します。
標準偏差（STDEVP）の関数が違うところとCASE式が微妙に違った気がします。

```
/* データ作成 */
DROP TABLE TEST_TABLE;

CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE (
    ID VARCHAR(8),
    NAME VARCHAR(32),
    SUBJECT VARCHAR(16),
    POINT INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_TEST_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (ID, NAME, SUBJECT)
);

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10001', 'John', 'Japanese', 50);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10001', 'John', 'English', 80);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10001', 'John', 'Math', 40);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10001', 'John', 'Science', 60);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10001', 'John', 'History', 50);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10002', 'Lisa', 'Japanese', 60);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10002', 'Lisa', 'English', 20);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10002', 'Lisa', 'Math', 20);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10002', 'Lisa', 'Science', 20);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10002', 'Lisa', 'History', 100);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10003', 'Peter', 'Japanese', 10);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10003', 'Peter', 'English', 10);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10003', 'Peter', 'Math', 10);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10003', 'Peter', 'Science', 10);
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID, NAME, SUBJECT, POINT) VALUES ('10003', 'Peter', 'History', 10);
/* SELECT */
SELECT
     T1.ID         ID
    ,T1.NAME       NAME
    ,T1.SUBJECT    SUBJECT
    ,T1.POINT      POINT
    ,CASE WHEN T2.STDRD = 0 THEN 50 /* 0除算 禁止 */
     ELSE ROUND((T1.POINT - T2.AVRG) / T2.STDRD * 10 + 50, 0) /* 整数 */
     END STDRD
FROM
    TEST_TABLE T1
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
              SUBJECT
             ,STDEVP(POINT) STDRD
             ,AVG(POINT) AVRG
        FROM
            TEST_TABLE
        GROUP BY
            SUBJECT
    ) T2
ON
    T1.SUBJECT = T2.SUBJECT
ORDER BY
    ID, NAME, SUBJECT
;
```

Comment: 一度group by してしまっているので、`SELECT (point-STD(point) )/AVG(point)*10+50 from test_table　GROUP BY subject;`では無理なのですが、どうすれば良いですか？

Comment: ああ、そういうことですか。テーブルの形がどうなっているのかわからないので漠然とした答えになりますが、上記SQLを括弧でくくってテーブル化して教科でjoinすればいいと思います。

Comment: 解答書き直しました。ただし、MySQLではないですが、ほとんど同じはずです。CASEのかわりにIFも使えます。